# Caching the entire response (HTML, js, json, ecc) only for non-logged in users

Tags: python, django

I love django-staticgenerator. Unfortunately you can't use it in cases in which you have to display different content depending on the user, plus is not being actively developed.

Is it possible to return the cached response only to non-logged in users?

I saw an app that used nginx to do it, is it possible to do it with apache?

Has anybody tried this solution and can you suggest if there is any actively developed django app that serves this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True`? Assuming whatever caching you're using utilizes Django's cache framework, that should do the trick.

Comment: +1 for mentioning something i didn't know, but I do want to use the cache framework for logged in users. For anonymous users I would like to serve the entire cached page without even hitting the database, as I already do on some websites, included mine, which load very fast.

Comment: That's exactly what that setting does. It only enables the cache for anonymous users. Logged in users will not longer be served anything from the cache. It will automatically affect templates by itself, and if your static files app uses the Django cache framework to cache file references, it will disable that as well.

Comment: You haven't understood my question Chris.
I found some alternatives:
http://ringce.com/hyde
http://www.alrond.com/en/2008/feb/23/static-generator-pro/